# Is it impossible to make an electron app MSI installer that is perMachine and not perUser?

Tags: electron, wix, electron-builder, squirrel.windows

I need to make an MSI from an electron app to bundle with another MSI that is also set to per machine and not per user. It appears this combination of things does not exist.

**Electron-Builder squirrelWindows**: Allows for MSI creation with `squirrelWindows` and setting `msi` boolean to true, but there is no `perMachine` option.
https://www.electron.build/configuration/squirrel-windows

**Electron-Builder NSIS**: Has the `perMachine` option but not for MSIs obviously.
https://www.electron.build/configuration/nsis

**Electron-Wix-MSI**: Creates MSI, but do not see ability to change the `perMachine` flag.
https://github.com/felixrieseberg/electron-wix-msi

**Windows-installer**: Creates MSI, no option for `perMachine`
https://github.com/electron/windows-installer

### EDIT - SOLUTION

These pull request changes on electron-wix-msi fixed my problem:
https://github.com/felixrieseberg/electron-wix-msi/pull/138

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a pull request/branch on electron-wix-msi tailored to fix my problems: https://github.com/felixrieseberg/electron-wix-msi/pull/138

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I've packaged multiple Electron apps per-machine.  It's just a bunch of files.  Potentially a whole bunch of files.  For the ones with an unpacked node_modules directory I just use heat in a prebuild step to author the components.  Other then that  it's just like any other app.